# Combine Promise.race with array of data as a parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have an array with 10+ data objects.

I want to check if one of `checkData` promise get success data with provided data parameter. I don't care which one was success, I just want to check if one from dataSet success.

Is it possible to use Promise.race in loop or map function like in below?

```
return Promise.race(
    dataSet.map(item => {
        checkData(item) // checkData return a Promise
    })
)
.then(...)
.catch(...)
```

I guess something like this could be done, If I pass array of promises to race method, it works, but I want to do this without paste 10 times(sometimes more) function that return promise.

Many thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Not sure if this was just a typo or not, but you need to return the promise inside that callback.

Comment: Exactly. :) I forgot to return promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map function return new array. You have to return element in your map function. if checkData returns promises you ahve to return it in map function

then you should have this:

```
return Promise.race(
dataSet.map(item => {
    return checkData(item) // checkData return a Promise
}));
```

Comment: Or you could remove `{}` which gives you implicit return.